# mercurial report on lines of code but on subdirectory deeper

Tags: mercurial

I am using following command on the root directory of our mercurial repository:

```
hg churn -d "2015-8-30 to 2016-7-27" . > out.txt
```

It yields a report like following :

```
user1               28305 
user2               15281
```

but there is a directory structure underneeth and actually i need reports per module and the module is 1 directory deeper than the root. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Is there also a way to get this same report to be limited for only a certain group of users, I am only interested in my team. And want to know who delivered the most lines of code, not that it matters quality is more important but it is an indication. I want to know which modules we touched and how much and my whom, so we know better where the expertise really is in a more objective fashion.

So the report should be something like this :

```
module 1:
user1 1000
user2 2000
module 2:
user1 3000
module 3:
user2 500
```

and so on.
There are perhaps 300 modules in our software so it is not easy to list them all one by one, without some kind of trick or script.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `hg churn` to only make reports for explicitly included directories with the `--include` option:

```
$ hg churn -I some_subdirectory/
```

See `hg help churn` for more information.

Comment: There are 300 subdirectories, do I have to mention them in -I one by one ?

Comment: No, you can use a fileset. See `hg help filesets`.